# What is the purpose of the tabs div when logged out?

Tags: theming

I am using a Bartik theme and am getting some extra padding in between the breadcrumbs and page title. Using firebug I discovered that there is an empty div which is displayed when I am logged out.

What is the purpose of this div? I thought it's only used in logged in mode... Is there a way to remove it from logged out mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tabs div will contain links even when logged out on some pages, such as the user page, where logged-out users can choose to either "Create new account" "Login" or "Request new password" by using the tabs.

Instead of removing it you can prevent it from taking up space when empty using CSS to remove the padding and margins on the div.